# How to use Pub/Sub message attributes in cloud scheduler

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler

I am trying to use google cloud scheduler to schedule a job. According to documentation, we can publish a payload to pub/sub, but is there a way to send message attributes?

Comment: Since you cannot change the message attributes in Cloud Scheduler except manually, why try to include static attributes? I would create a Cloud Function to publish to Pub/Sub and then call Cloud Function from Cloud Scheduler. Cloud Functions can specify message attributes via a library call.

Comment: we are doing that now. but I was trying to see if I can avoid cloud function.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `gcloud` beta command line tools to set the attributes:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/scheduler/jobs/create/pubsub

```
gcloud beta scheduler jobs create pubsub <JOB> --schedule "0 9 1 * *" --topic <TOPIC> --message-body "test" --attributes key1=value1,key2,value2
```

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/scheduler/jobs/update/pubsub#--update-attributes